# Ubuntu VM in Vmware running on top of Gentoo

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-server, gentoo

I want to know if the following architechture is possible and if so, what is the best way to implement it? :

A dedicated server running a linux gentoo distribution on top of which I want to install a virtualizaion system (preferably vmware but which product/version?) then deploy inside of it a VM of Ubuntu 10.04.

I also want to know the remote procedure to achieve such configuration (knowing that I would start with a machine already containing the gentoo distribution).

I believe that Vmware Vsphere (ESXi) is not suitable for my case and Vmware player does not allow remote access (Am I wrong?) and finally Vmware server is sort of discontinued. 
I'm a little lost between al these versions!

I'm open to any other suggestions

Comment: What's wrong with my question? It seems that some people have nothing to do but downvoting questions they don't find tasty or they are unable to answer!!! How lame!

Comment: The downvotes are likely as a result of a combination of the following speculative reasons: 1) The question implies a complete misunderstanding of virtualization, 2) Doesn't show due diligence in research, 3) Combines multiple large questions into one post, and 4) doesn't appear to be related to professional systems administration. My downvote is largely as a result of 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 and 4 but especially 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vmware ESXi requires a dedicated machine. Vmware server is EOL, and Player is made for low-needs desktop virtualization.

If you have a chance, try installing ESXi on a dedicated machine, and installing both Ubuntu and Gentoo as virtual machines inside it.

If not, try [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)... it has a headless mode, allows remote administration, works quite good, and it's free.

Comment: The main idea is to start working with the preinstalled gentoo distribution and get ubuntu running on top of it. I think that Virtualbox is quite promising. Now I'll have to dig all the procedure details to install it on a remote dedicated server. Thank you.

Comment: just run "emerge virtualbox-bin" :)

Comment: Thanx a lot, I'll definitely give it try :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically virtualizing Ubuntu on top of Gentoo should be no problem.

I'm though not sure you need a VMWare product. Remote access is pretty much always possible if you just log in to the VM via SSH or VNC (given the fact that you let the VM have internet access)

But maybe you should also look into [KVM](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/KVM) or [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Comment: VMware esxi is free.

Comment: I did not know that. But it needs a dedicated machine.

Comment: Yes that right it only works on bare metal, that's why it's not suitable for me. I'll have a look on KVM and Virtualbox. Thanks

Comment: Linux Vserver is another technically suitable and high-performance option, although considering the level of the original question, I'm not sure the @Sidou can handle setting that up.